# How to solve this question with Itô lemma?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $$M(t) = \int_{0}^t Y (u)dB(u).$$
where $$E \left[ \int_{0}^t Y^2(u)du\right] < \infty.$$ Use Itô’s rule to find the
differential $dQ$ of the process $$Q(t) = M^2(t) −
 \int_{0}^t  Y^2(u)du$$ and to conclude that
the process $Q$ is a martingale. In particular, argue that this implies $$E[M^2(t)] =
E\left[
 \int_{0}^t Y^2(u)du\right].$$

I just learn stochastic calculus recently, how should I tackle the $d(M^2(t))$, in order to get $dQ$? And what should I do next.

p.s. The proof for martingale part (Done.)

Comment: @saz and OP: How can you show using Itos rule, that Q is a martingale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying Itô's formula (for $f(x)=x^2$) yields

$$\begin{align*} M_t^2-M_0^2 &= 2 \int_0^t M_s \, dM_s + \int_0^t \langle M \rangle_s \\ &= 2 \int_0^t M_s Y_s \, dB_s + \int_0^t Y_s^2 \, ds \end{align*}$$

where we have used that

$$\langle M \rangle_s = Y_s^2 \, ds.$$

Consequently,

$$Q_t = 2 \int_0^t M_s Y_s \, dB_s,$$

i.e.

$$dQ_t = 2 M_t Y_t \, dB_t.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! That's easy to follow :D

Comment: How can you know that $Q$ really is a martingale? Don't you need something like $E\left[\int_{0}^t M^2_u Y^2_u du\right]<\infty$?

Comment: @user4514 Where did I claim that $Q$ is a martingale?

Comment: I thought this was part of the statement you wanted to proof with your answer. But yes, you did not claim this.